# Cosets of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=   {\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{R}) $ and $H={\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Prove that for any $ a,b \in G $ that the cosets $aH$ and $ bH$ are equal if and only if $\det(a) =\det(b) $.

One thing I am sure is important is that $ \forall h \in H $ the $\det(h) =1 $

What is confusing me is that h is one element and H is a set of elements im having trouble making the argument on infinite elements on one element.

please keep you answer as straightforward as possible i have found some similar questions on stack exchange but the answers were all incomprehensible with the amount of abstract algebra i have done.

Comment: Do you know that $aH=bH$ iff $b^{-1}a\in H$?

Comment: Have you tried writing out the generic definitions for cosets of a subgroup $H \le G$ (and conditions under which two cosets are the same) and the substituting in your specific stuff?

Comment: @EricWofsey No i dont know that i thought that i was trying to prove that $b^{-1} a \in H$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One direction is clear: aH=bH implies in particular $b\in aH$, i.e. b=ah for some $h\in H$, so $det(b)=det(ah)=det(a)det(h)=det(a)$.

For the other direction: if $det(a)=det(b)$, then $det(a^{-1}b)=\frac{1}{det(a)}det(b)=1$, so $a^{-1}b\in H$. Denote $h=a^{-1}b$, then $b=ah$, in particular $b\in aH$ and thus $bH=aH$.

Comment: omg thats so simple!